# How to merge two dataframes in Pandas using the most recent time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

position =

```
  id  time    x    y    z
  T1  1000  100  100  120
  T1  2000   50   50  120
  T2  1200  100  200  120
```

event =

```
  id   time       event
  T1   1500     stopped    
  T2   1200  travelling
```

desired result =

```
  id   time       event    x    y    z  
  T1   1500     stopped  100  100  120    
  T2   1200  travelling  100  200  120
```

I can merge on id and time columns if the times are the same, is there an elegant solution to get the most recent time?

Comment: Can you explain why the [x,y,z] value for `time=1500` are `[100,100,120]` ?
How's time=1000 more recent to 1500 rather than 1200?

Comment: @SerialLazer Because the id = T1, there are multiple machines that are generating events and positions

Comment: why for T1 1500 you choose T1 1000 and not  T1 2000?

Comment: @SandervandenOord because 1000 was the most recent to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [.merge_asof()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for this problem. 
For this both your df's need to be sorted by time.

Code example:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

position_text = """
  id  time    x    y    z
  T1  1000  100  100  120
  T1  2000   50   50  120
  T2  1200  100  200  120
"""

event_text = """
  id   time       event
  T1   1500     stopped    
  T2   1200  travelling
"""

df_position = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(position_text), 
    sep='\s+', header=0,
).sort_values(by=['time', 'id'])

df_event = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(event_text), 
    sep='\s+', header=0
).sort_values(by=['time', 'id'])

df_result = pd.merge_asof(
    df_event, df_position, 
    on='time', by='id', 
    direction='backward',
)

df_result.sort_values(by='id')
```

This results in:

```
id  time    event       x   y   z
T1  1500    stopped     100 100 120
T2  1200    travelling  100 200 120
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is extremely performant compared to doing something similar in SQL, thanks very much for this merge_asof is a fantastic method